# Resharper shows all tests of a text fixture are passed but text fixture fails

Tags: nunit, resharper-6.0

I'm using resharper with nunit. As seen in the picture all test are passed in a text fixture but text fixture fails. All my test cases are parameterized by the way. How does this happen?

When I click on the text Fixture it says: Failed:Child test failed

[image]

Comment: When you click on fixture what's written in description window?

Comment: have you tried running your tests in the NUnit console runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded nunit installer and run the test with nunit GUI. nunit showed 2 failed tests. I fixed them and now resharper shows it right. Looks like it is a bug with resharper 6.